# mongoose returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, next.js, server

im trying to fetch chats where the members are equal to a particular ID each time it returns empty array

below is my schema

```
import mongoose, {Schema, models} from "mongoose";

const chatSchema = new Schema({

   members: {
        userId:String,
        postOwner:String
   },
    chat:[{
        username:String,
        message:String,
        senderId:String
    }]
},
{timestamps:true})

const Chat = models.Chat || mongoose.model("Chat", chatSchema)
export default Chat
```

And here is the code to get the chats

````
export async function GET(req,{params}){
  let {ids} = params
    const id = ids[0]
    console.log(id)
  await connectDB()
  const chat = await Chat.find({$or:[{members:{userId:id}}, {members:{postOwner:id}}]})
  console.log(chat)
  if(chat){
    return NextResponse.json({message:'chat found',chat})
  }else{
    return NextResponse.json({message:'no chat found'})
  }
  
}```



The above code keeps returning an empty array
````

Comment: Try: `const chat = await Chat.find({$or:[{"members.userId":id}, {"members.postOwner":id}]})`

Comment: I tried it, still an empty array

Comment: And there are object in d chat array

Comment: thanks for the assist, but I'm still getting empty array

Comment: Even when I passed an id that doesn't exist in any members object, I still get an empty array and status code of 200

Comment: Try logging the object that is being passed to Chat.find so you can see the details of the query.

Comment: Thanks, the code was actually working fine, I was passing a wrong id